# The use of 'A number' in Mathematical Language

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, predicate-logic

When studying Mathematics, we see expressions with equality with one or more variables, such as $x+1=2$, I've always seen this as an expression which states $(number)+1 = 2$ where $number$ could be many numbers depending on potential values that can be subbed in yielding a $true$ or $false$ answer, a predicate that can depend on values of $x$.

Recently I have learnt of Existential quantification and I perceive something like the following:
$∃xP(x)$ as being 'there exists a value of the variable $x$ such that $P(x)$ (is true)'

I have seen it written as 'there exists *a number* $x$ such that (for example) $x+1=1$

This seems to contradict my view, as it seems $x$ is a *particular number* in their view of $x$ and can only represent this particular number, instead of being something than varies in a Domain $D$ and can be substituted into.

We also see terminology like where $x$ is a number, this seems ambiguous, is the correct interpretation 'there is one number $x$ or, $x$ represents a place where a number can be assigned or substituted for $x$. **Is there a particular difference between 'there is a number $x$ such that...' and ' there exists a value of $x$ such that...'**

Is there a distinction between a variable and what can be substituted into based on context as opposed to whether they are bound or free (as these could be considered free variables still).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "there exists" or the symbol $\exists$ **does** change the meaning of a sentence. Plain "$x+1=2$" by itself does not usually mean the same as "there exists a number $x$ such that $x+1=2$".

The meaning of just $x+1=2$ depends on context: if nothing is known about $x$, it's as you say a predicate which could be used with multiple values of $x$ to  get a statement which is true or false. In predicate logic, we could say $P(x)$ is "$x+1=2$". Then $P(10)$ is false and $P(1)$ is true. But if $x$ was already defined to be some value, then $x+1=2$ is already a true or false statement.

Adding the existence quantifier, we also get a statement which is true or false. $\exists x P(x)$ (or $\exists x . P(x)$ or $\exists x : P(x)$) reads as "there exists a number $x$ such that $x+1=2$". This statement is true since the value $1$ satisfies the predicate.

Also note $\exists$ or "there exists..." actually means "there exists at least one ...". You may also see $\exists!$ to say "there exists exactly one..." or "there exists a unique..."

A few more examples:

$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2=1$ — "There exists a real number $x$ such that $x^2=1$ — true

$\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2=-1$ — "There exists a real number $x$ such that $x^2=-1$ —  false

$\exists! x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2=1$ — "There exists a unique real number $x$ such that $x^2=1$ — false

Comment: it seems strange if there is a predicate that can change on $x$ to say 'there is a number $x$, such that...', it seems like $x$ has to represent a particular value, is there a difference between 'there is a number $x$ such that....' and 'there exists a value of $x$ such that...'

Comment: Those two sentences do mean the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In many mathematical texts, when a new variable is introduced, the type of quantification (existential / universal) is often implied and not explicitly stated. It would be wrong to assume existential quantification everywhere.

Existential quantification ($\exists x P(x)$) is used to talk about the existence of a value for $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true. But there is a way to talk about the whole range of values for which $P(x)$ is true, and then you can substitute any value for $x$ (and not just a particular number), as long as $P$ holds for that value.

The solution is to use universal quantification. For example, the statement $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$ can be read as 'For all $x$ for which $P(x)$ holds, $Q(x)$ holds too'. Put differently, when the text starts with something like 'Let $x$ be such that $P(x)$' and then goes on to prove $Q(x)$, then the text uses universal quantification and formally it proves that $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$.

Altogether, an equality that contains variables should not be read alone. One should look at the text to see how these variables are quantified. Phrases like 'Suppose some $x$ such that ...' or 'Assume any $x$ ...' or 'Let $x$ be such that ...' mean universal quantification, while 'There is an $x$ such that ...' means existential.

Comment: can we not substitute a value for which $P(x)$ is false for example a simple way is the elementary method of solving an equation by trial-and-error.

Comment: @user1007028 Well, in the case of $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$, if you replace $x$ with a value for which $P$ does not hold, then the implication is useless: you cannot know whether $Q$ holds too about that value. So, this move just doesn't make sense. But if you replace the $x$ with something for which $P$ holds, then because of that implication, you can conclude that $Q$ also holds.

Comment: of course, I misunderstood slightly

Answer (score 0):

Consider the (satisfiable but logically non-valid) predicate $$(-1)^x=1.\tag#$$

The “truth status” of a predicate depends on its interpretation:

- In the context of $\mathbb R,$
  predicate $(\#)$ is a conditional equation, i.e., true for some values in the domain of its variable $x,$ so

  1. $∃x\; (-1)^x=1$ is a true statement,
  2. $∀ x\; (-1)^x=1$ is a false statement.
- In the context of $2\mathbb Z,$ predicate $(\#)$ is an
  identity, i.e., true for all values of $x,$ so

  1. $∃x\; (-1)^x=1$ is a true statement,
  2. $∀ x\; (-1)^x=1$ is a true statement.
- In the context of $\mathbb Z{\setminus}2\mathbb Z$ (i.e., the set of
  odds), predicate $(\#)$ is inconsistent, i.e., true for no value of $x,$ so

  1. $∃x\; (-1)^x=1$ is a false statement,
  2. $∀ x\; (-1)^x=1$ is a false statement.