# How to interpret an identity like $\sin(A+B) ≡ \sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$ using quantifiers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, terminology, predicate-logic

We can define using the '$\equiv$' an 'identity', for example the trigonometric one I gave in the title. Given two expressions connected by triple bar, for example, $\sin(A+B) \equiv \sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B),$ can we define the identity as being equivalent to the quantified statement:
$$\forall A\forall B(\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B))?$$

The difficulty I have is say we have two angles and the relation is such that $A$ is a function of $B$ depend on each other, we should in theory be able to add them no matter what their values may be at any time, so the use of the ≡ symbol to signify that the two sides will be equal no matter what values they will have at any time (for each $A$ there is now a corresponding B as $A=f(B)$ for some function $f$). However, the double universal quantifier doesn't seem like a statement we can make as for any $A$, it is not possible for $B$ to vary in its entire range in the domain of discourse, as $A$ is a function of $B$ there can only be perhaps one or two possible values of $B$, is the quantified statement simply incorrect or is there a way to get past this?

As an addition, perhaps it is fine to use universal quantification because it is about truth *if* the variables were able to take those values, ignoring if we have certain restrictions that may not allow a certain combination of values to take place.

Comment: If $\forall A\forall B(P(A,B))$ is true then so is $\forall A(P(A,f(A))).$ I don't see the difficulty. If you think you can go back to the original trig identity and say that it only applies to $A$ and $B$ subject to certain constraints, you're no longer talking about the original trig identity but rather you have some weaker statement.

Comment: hi user37577. indeed, the way you have quantified it is absolutely correct! and it *is* the case that "for any $A$ it is possible for $B$ to vary in its entire range in the domain of discourse". why do you have the impression that "$A$ is a function of $B$"? what function $f$ do you have in mind? $A$ and $B$ in this statement are completely independent

Comment: Universal quantifiers commute, so you don’t have to worry about order in choosing $A$ and $B$.  You could write $\forall A,B$ or $\forall B\forall A$ and have the same meaning.

Comment: [Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics)#Logic_and_universal_algebra) are universally quantified: $\forall x \forall y [(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy]$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom It could be any $f$, $A=2B$ $A=B^2$ any of your choosing, this would mean that B can only have values in its range for certain A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we can define using the '$\equiv$' an 'identity', for example the trigonometric one I gave in the title

Trigonometric identities are not identities-by-definition.

Also worth noting: the term ‘identity’ has contrasting usages in mathematics; as does [the $\text‘≡\text’$ symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4332511/21813).

> $A$ is a function of $B$ depend on each other,

There is no dependency between $A$ and $B$ (as explained in [our previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4395904/21813)), because the title equation’s solution set is the entirety of $\mathbb R^2,$ *not* a proper subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ It is precisely because that equation is universally quantified that we, by definition, call it an **identity**. (This pertains to the second bullet point of [our other previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4391911/21813).)

On the other hand (the previous link's first bullet point), if a two-variable equation (e.g., $xy=10)$ is satisfied by some but not all points in $\mathbb R^2,$ then its solution set’s $x$- and $y$-coordinates generally *do* depend on each other, and it is a **conditional equation** instead of an identity.

Summary:

- That equation $P$’s solution set’s $x,y$ are independent typically corresponds to $$\forall (x,y) \; P(x,y)$$
- That equation $P$’s solution set $S$’s $x,y$ are dependent typically corresponds to $$\forall(x,y){\in}S \; P(x,y)$$

Comment: In my case they *would* be satisfied by all values of the variables, however if they cannot actually in practice ever be able to have that combination of values without invalidating another relation that I wish to be true if they are to be functions of one another.

Comment: 1. There's no need for "would": your specified identity *is* satisfied by all $(A,B)$ couples.  $\quad$ 2. The rest of your sentence is grammatically incoherent; in any case, your specified identity invalidates **no** correct relation, and $A$ and $B$ **aren't** functions of each other, and that's that about that. $\quad$ 3. You want to additionally impose a constraint $A=f(B)$ on that equation? Then it's no longer an *identity*, and my Answer's final line explicitly explains how you might formalise it as a *conditional equation*.

Comment: Conditional equation, so the use of triple bar is not correct when we impose a constraint, I thank you.